# Delete Hundreds of thousands of files by date

Tags: python, perl

I want a script that can check the age of files in different directories and delete those that exceed an expiration age. There can be hundreds of thousand of files with different creation dates. Some directories don't have that many files. There are approximately 100 directories. The directories have different expiration ages. I was thinking YAML for configuration and Perl 5 or Python 3 as the scripting language. Which would get the job done faster? Can this be done in a few hours (3-5) or would it take days?

The script will run on Linux.

Comment: What defines the expiration age?  Creation date normally isn't a thing so do you mean modification or access date?  What version of find does your system have?

Comment: As is this question is asking to solve a vague and hypothetical problem which is more likely to be closed.  Please read through the [help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/asking) on asking questions and try to narrow your question down to a specific problem that has an objective answer.

Comment: Depending on how complicated the "different directories have different expire times" part is, this could even be a shell script calling a variation on `find ... -type d -not -newer ... -delete`.

Comment: It is a Linux system so it has GNU Linux find. I agree it can be modification date, although I think the files are copied into the directory once and not modified. I would read some sort of configuration file for the directories and expire ages, which is why I thought it would be easier to in Perl or Python.

Comment: @SethF: Not every linux system has GNU find and that also doesn't tell us the version.

Comment: Since I have a variety of directories and files I think a shell script would be more of a hassle to write. Does Perl or Python have a way to return all of files older than a certain date/time or would I have to examine each file?

Comment: If you were able to solve the issue you wouldn't be asking here.  Shell scripts aren't great for many things but working with files is exactly where they excel.  If you really want an answer to your question you have to modify it to be answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The directories have different expiration ages.

So you would a need a loop and max. 100 calls of `find`.

I think this would take only seconds, if you use the `find ... -delete` method (or something else as direct). *How* this gets called is secondary.

The configuration file can be simplified maybe to a 2-column file.

One way to optimize would be to group dirs with the same exp. date together, like:

```
find dir1 dir2 dir3 -type f -mtime  +7 -delete
```

(delete regular files that are at least 8 days old based on their last modification time).

```
find dir4 dir5 dir6 -type f -mtime +30 -delete
```

(delete regular files that are at least 31 days old based on their last modification time).

---

So you don't even need perl, but for a comfortable YAML parsing, and some list sorting, sure.

---

Come to think of it: you could use the "find-ML" directly:

```
find dir1 dir2 dir3\
 d7 d13\
 d42 d44 d46\
 -type f -mtime  +7 -delete


find dir4 dir5 dir6\
 d11 d19\
 d61 d62 d63\
 -type f -mtime  +30 -delete


find ...\
 ...\
 -type f -mtime  +XY -delete
```

You can say it is ugly by mixing up data and code - but it is 95% data in your case. The code is just for grouping the dirs with the number of days, just as the YAML file would do. This assignment of expiration dates to the directories has maybe some rules? Or it has to be done be hand anyway: why not as direct as that? (THAT is what takes some time to set up, and maybe maintain)

Comment: I just need some file with the directories and expiration ages I could pass to a script. It sounds like a shell script would be the best solution.

Comment: This site is allergic to "best" (=opinion). I looked up YAML - looks simple and neat. It really is your choice. Do you want a portable perl version (with `unlink LIST` maybe, and no `system` call) or a "cool" minimalistic linux script, maybe depending on GNU find?

Comment: I wanted to find the most feasible solution with decent performance. Maybe either Perl or Python could do it. YAML would be fine.

Comment: Sorry "feasible" also is open to debate :) BTW I found a surprising solution, see above. Just copy some of your dirs and do some tests, with 'time find ... `.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about find, but management wants me to use Python which will be OK since I've never done Python before. I'll remember not to ask opinion questions in the future.